# Bootstrap grid and span

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm having trouble getting span and the grid working properly on my bootstrap homepage.  I want "contact" and "Store Hours" to sit side by side at span 6 each, but they're going under each other at the width of the hero unit above it that holds info. How can I get the span to take hold?

**home.html**

```
    <div class="center hero-unit">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <h4>
            //fill with store info
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="center hero-unit"> 
        <h1> Contact </h1>
        <h4> 314.555.3000 </h4>
        <h4> 100 St. Louis Ave </h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span6">
        <div class="center hero-unit"> 
        <h1> Store Hours </h1>
        <h4> Monday - Thursday // 10:30 AM to 8:00 PM</h4> 
        <h4> Friday - Saturday // 10:30 AM to 9:00 PM</h4>
        <h4> Sunday // Closed </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**stylesheet.css**

```
.hero-unit {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    margin: 90px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #444;
    border-color: #3399FF;
}
```

Comment: What Bootstrap version are you using? For your examples, it seems like version 2, but the given answers are for version 3.

Comment: I used some code from one of my older projects like <div class="span6"> when Bootstrap 2 was current and didn't realize it that changed for Bootstrap 3.  <div class="col-md-6">&nbsp;</div> from the answer below fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmhhh, if I'm not mistaken bootstrap classes are: "col-md-6" or "col-lg-6" , etc
Also, you need to wrap the colummns in a "row"

You should try something like:

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-md-6">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Also, you are closing 1 div too many, the `</div>` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="center hero-unit">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <h4>
                //fill with store info
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="center hero-unit">
            <h1> Contact </h1>
            <h4> 314.555.3000 </h4>
            <h4> 100 St. Louis Ave </h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="center hero-unit">
            <h1> Store Hours </h1>
            <h4> Monday - Thursday // 10:30 AM to 8:00 PM</h4>
            <h4> Friday - Saturday // 10:30 AM to 9:00 PM</h4>
            <h4> Sunday // Closed </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

else Bootstrap 2 :

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="center hero-unit">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <h4>
                //fill with store info
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span6">
        <div class="center hero-unit">
            <h1> Contact </h1>
            <h4> 314.555.3000 </h4>
            <h4> 100 St. Louis Ave </h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span6">
        <div class="center hero-unit">
            <h1> Store Hours </h1>
            <h4> Monday - Thursday // 10:30 AM to 8:00 PM</h4>
            <h4> Friday - Saturday // 10:30 AM to 9:00 PM</h4>
            <h4> Sunday // Closed </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```